# Are bonus and rebate taxable?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Suppose

- I purchase something from a company, and I get some rebate.
- I open an account with a bank, and I get some bonus.

Questions (for The United States)

1. To me, are rebate and bonus taxable income when I report my personal income tax
   in 1040 form?
2. To the company, is the rebate excluded when calculating its taxable
   income?
3. To the bank, is the bonus excluded when calculating its taxable
   income?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5):

The classic case of getting a toaster from the bank is treated as interest. So it will be  taxable income for the customer.

For the rebate, or for that matter a coupon, it is not a taxable event for the customer. They are just a complicated sale.

For the bank, the toaster is interest they are paying.

For the company I am not sure if the rebate reduces their income, or increases their expenses.

Comment: Thanks! "For the bank, the toaster is interest they are paying", does the bonus/toaster reduce the bank's taxable income?

Comment: The toaster is treated like all the other dividends/interest they pay. The fact that it is an item and not an electronic transaction is immaterial.

Comment: Thanks! Does dividends/interest they pay reduce their income before computing their tax?

Comment: +1 There's a current case with Citibank tied to bonus miles given on an airline. Since the miles were for opening the account, they are income. In the normal course of monthly charges, they'd be a (tax-free) rebate.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Some recent offers that I have been getting say that the bonus miles that they are offering for opening the account will actually be awarded after I have charged $1000 on the account. This presumably makes them an extra rebate on that first $1000. Other charges give a rebate of one mile per dollar charged.

Comment: Dilip, understood. I believe the Citibank situation was they offered a bonus simply for opening the account. The bonus based on usage should still be considered a rebate.

Comment: For the company, the rebate **reduces their income**, that is exactly why it is not a taxable event to the customer. Had it been a (deductible) expense - the customer would have to declare it as an income.